# How do I use ufw to open ports on ipv4 only?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ufw

Whenever I run a command like `ufw allow 22`, ufw automatically adds the firewall rules to both ipv4 and ipv6. If I want to only open a port on ipv4, is there a way to do so? Something like `ufw allow 22 proto ipv4`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just have to use the [fuller syntax](https://manpages.debian.org/ufw#RULE_SYNTAX) and specify an address (range).

For example, allow connections to TCP port 22 on all IPv4 addresses:

```
ufw allow proto tcp to 0.0.0.0/0 port 22
```

Comment: I don't think this actually is a complete answer. Please see mine below. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

I would edit the ufw config file itself to turn off IPv6:

`sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`

Change the line that says: `IPV6=yes` to `IPV6=no` then restart the ufw service. You can even run `sudo ufw reload` if the ufw instance is already enabled.

This worked for me to ensure that all the rules I add are only added to IPv4.

Thanks

Comment: It works fantastic, and it even causes deletion of all the duplicate IPv6 rules immediately upon reload. Thank you

Comment: @spaceman no problem, glad it worked out

Comment: Warning: All IPv6 rules will be deleted and **not** be restored if setting `IPV6=yes` again.

Comment: Big question, does it gonna skip v6 ports and let them free/open?

Comment: @M.Rostami no. It disables IPv6 completely and removes all current IPv6 rules.

Comment: This will block all the incoming ipv6 traffic, it will prevent ipv6 users from accessing your sites!

Comment: @james-see DNS amplification attacks are still possible using IPv4.

Comment: @MichaelMior source? I would like to know more and test for this.

Comment: @james-see There's nothing inherent to DNS amplification attacks that requires IPv6. If you read any article that describes DNS amplification, you likely won't see any mention of IPv4 vs IPv6 because it's IPV6 is not necessary.

Comment: @MichaelMior can you please read the cloudflare article I linked? “ The DNS configuration for IPv6 will be different from IPv4. In addition to the connection issues, there’s also a higher risk for DNS attacks, primarily DNS amplification attacks. They are usually used to strengthen distributed denial-of-service or botnet attacks.” Are you saying they are wrong? This is why I asked for a source.

Comment: @james-see I read the article and I'm not saying it's wrong. The article says there is a *higher* risk, not that there is no risk with IPv4.

Comment: @MichaelMior ah, that makes more sense. you want me to fix my comment above that is not clear or specific regarding ip4 and may indicate the wrong thing depending on how you read it. I did not clearly say in the comment that there is not risk with IPv4. fixing now and probably just deleting the comment, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe only by subnet:

sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 22

More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html